# Map ICollection<Model> to List<ViewModel> using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper in my code. When mapped the collection, I've got this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Web.ViewModels.FirmMatterViewModel]
>   Map[ICollection`1,List`1](System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Web.Models.FirmMatter])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

This is the code how I do the mapping:

```
var clientMatters = 
    from cm in db.ClientMatters
        .Include(t => t.Billing)
        .Include(t => t.Billing.Office)
        .Include(t => t.Billing.Client)
        .Include(t => t.FirmMatters)
    select new ClientMatterIndexListViewModel
    {
        ClientMatterID = cm.ClientMatterID,
        BillingID = cm.BillingID,
        OfficeName = cm.Billing.Office.Name,
        ClientName = cm.Billing.Client.Name,
        ClientMatterNo = cm.ClientMatterNo,
        Description = cm.Description,
        FirmMatters = Mapper.Map<ICollection<FirmMatter>, List<FirmMatterViewModel>>(cm.FirmMatters)
    };
```

I have created the map for FirmMatter

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FirmMatter, FirmMatterViewModel>();
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: you should add Mapper.Map(FirmMatter, FirmMatterViewModel>(); to your code. For example, you can take a look at this link below;

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to Entities tries to translate `Map` method to SQL, which is obviously undoable. To avoid that error, you should convert query to enumerable before calling map:

```
var query = 
    from cm in db.ClientMatters
        .Include(t => t.Billing)
        .Include(t => t.Billing.Office)
        .Include(t => t.Billing.Client)
        .Include(t => t.FirmMatters)
    select cm;

var clientMatters = query.AsEnumerable().Select(cm => new ClientMatterIndexListViewModel
{
    ClientMatterID = cm.ClientMatterID,
    BillingID = cm.BillingID,
    OfficeName = cm.Billing.Office.Name,
    ClientName = cm.Billing.Client.Name,
    ClientMatterNo = cm.ClientMatterNo,
    Description = cm.Description,
    FirmMatters = Mapper.Map<ICollection<FirmMatter>, List<FirmMatterViewModel>>(cm.FirmMatters)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code but it generates a new error `A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause` I think it should end with select clause

Comment: Yep, I've forgotten to write it. Just add `select cm` at the end of query. I've also fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know you accepted an answer, but I would either not do this with AutoMapper, or do it with AutoMapper all the way.

The combination of `Include`s and `AsEnumerable()` is very inefficient because the SQL statement will SELECT all columns of all tables and pull this bloated result set into memory. And in the end you only need a very limited number of properties. Why not look for a way to only select the required data?

#### Without AutoMapper

A query without `AsEnumerable()` and AM and with an inlined projection is far more efficient:

```
var clientMatters = 
    from cm in db.ClientMatters
    select new ClientMatterIndexListViewModel
    {
        ClientMatterID = cm.ClientMatterID,
        BillingID = cm.BillingID,
        OfficeName = cm.Billing.Office.Name,
        ClientName = cm.Billing.Client.Name,
        ClientMatterNo = cm.ClientMatterNo,
        Description = cm.Description,
        FirmMatters = cm.FirmMatters.Select(fm => new FirmMatterViewModel { ... } }
    };
```

You don't need the Includes here, because the query doesn't return `ClientMatter` objects in which the collections and references can be Included. Using these navigation properties in the `select` is enough for EF to generate all required joins.

#### With AutoMapper

If you also define a mapping between `ClientMatter` and `ClientMatterIndexListViewModel`, you could use AutoMapper's `Project.To` method to get the same effect as in the previous query:

```
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
...

var clientMatters = db.ClientMatters
                      .Project().To<ClientMatterIndexListViewModel>();
```

To make this happen, `ClientMatterIndexListViewModel` should contain a property like this:

```
public IEnumerable<FirmMatterViewModel> FirmMatters { get; set; }
```